# Calling WSO2 Application Server Services from WSO2 WSF PHP with username token

Tags: wso2

I have tried calling WSO2 Application Server Service with WSO2 WSF PHP as a client. and bravo! success!.

Next step, i configure WSO2 Application Server Service with UserName Token enabled, and failed . :(

Any tutorial how to access/calling WSO2 Application Server Service with Username token enabled from WSO2 WSF PHP?

thanks alot...

Answer (score 0):

Did you see following guide on client side security http://wso2.org/project/wsf/php/2.0.0/docs/manual_content.html#6.6.